# Calculating the symbolic solution to a definite integral containing trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, riemann-zeta

It is verifiable numerically or with a computer algebra system (for example with Mathematica using `NIntegrate`) that the numerical solution to the following integral

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2 \cos (x)+1}\right) \, dx$

is equal to the numerical value of $\zeta(2)$ or to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$

Could this solution be calculated or determined symbolically or analytically?

Comment: You can find a solution due to Y. Sharifi (Problem 2) here:https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u25584h1674162p10667425